# Python equivalent for curl -b (--cookie)

Tags: python

I wish to convert a bash script that's currently using "curl -b 'cookie'" into a Python script. I've looked at Pycurl, but I couldnt' find a -b equivalent. There are also urllib and urllib2, but I couldn't see an easy way to replicate the line.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started.

http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.CookieJar

Answer (score 0):

You can use CookieJar.add_cookie_header to add your cookie to a http request header.